# Is there is a way to repair the paint as the new car?

Tags: paint, paint-scratches

Hi I own Renault Megane Mk3 for while and car's paint is almost full with small scratches due to hard cleaning, I know its stupid thing to make but it wasn't my fault. 
You will get how scratches look like in photos.

[image]

Thos circles that appears when a light reflect on car's surface.
 If photos are not clear I'll provide another photos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a fine grit rubbing compound and a buffing wheel to smooth out the clear coat, which actually has the scratches.

Part of the process of painting many vehicles is to buff out the clear coat once the paint job is complete.  The clear coat provides a clear protective layer for the paint and can be scratched lightly and repaired over time by using rubbing compound and the buffing wheel.

You would put the buffing wheel on the end of a drill.  This is what it looks like.

[image]

You can goto google and search rubbing compound.  The rubbing compound would need to be a low 'grit' level, meaning the particles should be smaller in order to remove the scratches you have.

Your scratches could be made by a buffing wheel using a very high grit level of rubbing compound which would put scratches into the clear coat rather than removing them.

So, use low grit compound and be patient with your buffing.  Follow it up with a waxing and it should improve the appearance dramatically.

Someone will probably post a better step by step methodology with grit levels and what not.  I've really just brushed over the top.

Comment: Is there is any experience needed in painting to use this? And is there is any possibility to make the paint worst than before if I did something wrong with the buffing wheel?

Comment: Watch this youtube video and you will understand.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tj6Rcd5VpE4

Comment: Thank you, I went to a workshop who told me he can do that and my paint is 90% repaired :D only deep ones stayed.

Comment: Excellent.  Very glad the answer was helpful.  Cheers!